# Is it possible to asynchronously query DocumentDB for all documents (i.e no paging)?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible, using the [DocumentDB .NET SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-sdk-dotnet/), to make run an  asynchronous query against the DB that returns all matching documents?

The answer answer to this StackOverflow question: [Querying Azure DocumentDB with ExecuteNextAsync returns fewer than MaxItemCount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120835/querying-azure-documentdb-with-executenextasync-returns-fewer-than-maxitemcount) indicates that:

> There are limits for how long a query will execute on DocumentDB.
>   ...
>   If these limits are hit, then a partial set of results may be returned.

I know that it's possible to overcome the above mentioned limit by iterating over paged results like so: ([source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/blob/d17c0ca5be739a359d105cf4112443f65ca2cb72/samples/code-samples/Queries/Program.cs#L554-L576))

```
List<Family> families = new List<Family>();

FeedOptions options = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1 };

var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Family>(collectionLink, options).AsDocumentQuery();

while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    foreach (Family family in await query.ExecuteNextAsync())
    {
        families.Add(family);
    }
}
```

My question is - Is this loop necessary? Might there be a more elegant way to tell the SDK to return all results available (without paging)?

Comment: I never use it because I manage my own paging with a lazy interface but I thought the toArray() method did what are asking for.

Comment: Can you try that using `CreateStoredProcedureQueryy`.
Like `client.CreateStoredProcedureQuery(collectionLink,"Select * from myColleciton");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop you have is the best way to perform enumerating across multiple requests since there is a bounded time execution on each request in DocumentDB.

You could wrap this code in an extension method to make it handy.

This is a good suggestion for DocumentDB team to add this support - 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-dotnet/issues